# How can i share media with my ionic app

Tags: javascript, mobile, ionic-framework

I want to share my images and videos with application which was developed with ionic framework. How can I share them?

Comment: share with social media?  whatsapp, facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cordova Sharing Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin); that plugin let you share "content" using a native dialog to select the app to share with, or you can specifiy some popular apps to use for sharing (Twitter, Facebook, ...).

You can easily share images, text and links, but there are some limitations (particularly for Facebook). If you want to build a custom image to use for share (say a text with an avatar) you can prepare the image in pure Javascript using an HTML5 canvas.

For more information you can check this [blog post](https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/html5-canvas-image-share-ionic-cordova), where the Cordova Sharing Plugin is used together with the HTML5 canvas approach.